# which audio format to use in android to store recording

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I am developing application which records voice from mic, currently I am storing recorded audio in wave file but size of wave is becoming an issue.

I came to know that android do not have mp3 decoder is it true? What would I do to store recorded audio in compressed form?

I am using AudioRecord class for recording and don't want to use MediaRecorder.

Comment: It depends where you going to play these files? Is it also Android device or maybe PC?

Comment: on various mobile devices..

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution for the size? Currently I use .3GP which has low quality.

Answer (score 2):

Using AudioRecord does not give you many options. It stores audio in PCM format only. You can lower size only by setting channel config to CHANNEL_IN_MONO and audio format to ENCODING_PCM_8BIT. Additionally, you can try to extend AudioRecord class and override read() method. Then you must convert audio yourself but that's not recommended.

I know you don't want this but the best option would be refactoring your code to use MediaRecorder. Here is example from reference documentation:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
 ...
 recorder.stop();
 recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
 recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

On this site http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core you have nice table presenting all supported formats taking into considerations Android versions. Try these AAC LC, AMR-NB, AMR-WB. Except sizes check the quality.

Comment: Problem while using MediaRecorder is, I want to implement play-pause- resume-stop functionality. which is hard to implement using MediaRecorder.

Comment: True, if you do you will end up with multiple audio files. You can either merge this files at the end or maybe consider sharing your audio recording as a folder with record parts. Playing them in a sequence will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Mp3 decoder but the default format which all android version will support is .mgp and .amr format which will be played using MediaPlayer and AudioPlayer classes by default

**Note**: This is not guarantee that all the players will support this extension , if it is not an android device

Comment: so what I have to do to reduce the size of my wave files? how do i convert them to .amr format?